# No useful info in developer console

Tags: android, crash, console, proguard

I have this error report :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=4
at com.skydev.xiomfy.MainActivity.h(Unknown Source)
at com.skydev.xiomfy.MainActivity.f(Unknown Source)
at com.skydev.xiomfy.x.run(Unknown Source)
```

How to have more details and have the line number of the error ? ("unknown source" does't give me where the app crashes...)

Is there a setting in my app code or in the developer console to have more datas on crash ?

Comment: You have an array with 1 element only. But you are trying to get the item with index = 4 (5th element). You can only get the item with index = 0. Search your code for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not poor. What are you seeing is the obfuscate stacktrace, due of proguard. You can use the `.map` file generated by proguard to restore the full stacktrace. You can find more info [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/retrace/examples.html#withverbose)